# Chained Promise in JS Not Waiting for Chained Function to Finish/Resolve

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm utilizing an async approach to an iteration in order to call several AJAX requests for each object inside an array called `rsPatients` (i.e., I use an `if` conditional instead of a `for` loop), and inside this iteration is a chained `Promise`.

```
function BuildBoardTable() {
    var objLength = Object.keys(rsPatients).length
    if (objLength === 0) {
        $('#tblMessageData').html('<tr style="vertical-align:top;"><td style="background-color:#EEE;" colspan="8">No Patients</td></tr>');
        return false;
    }
    var phoneNumber;
    var rsDevice;
    var counter = 0;

    getExternalData();

    function getExternalData() {
        if (counter < objLength) {
            var CaseNumber = rsPatients[counter].CaseNo;
            var Loc_Code = rsPatients[counter].LocationCode;

            getPhoneNumber(CaseNumber, Loc_Code).then(function () {
                console.log(counter);
                console.log('get1');                 //[breakpoint #1]
            }).then(function () {
                getDeviceData(CaseNumber, Loc_Code); //[breakpoint #2]
            }).then(function () {
                console.log('get2');                 //[breakpoint #4]
            }).then(function () {
                console.log('get3');                 //[breakpoint #5]
                counter++;
            }).finally(function () {
                getExternalData();                   //[breakpoint #6]
            });
        } else {
            counter = 0;
            $('#content-holder > .appwait').hide();
        }
    }

    function getPhoneNumber(CaseNumber, Loc_Code) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'api/Phone/PatientNumber',
                data: {
                    'case_no': CaseNumber,
                    'loc_code': Loc_Code
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    phoneNumber = result.Number;
                    console.log(result.Number);
                    resolve(result);
                },
                failure: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(xhr + ", " + status + ": " + error);
                    alert(xhr + ", " + status + ": " + error);
                    phoneNumber = '';
                    reject(error);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    function getDeviceData(CaseNumber, Loc_Code) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'api/Phone/PatientDevice',
            data: {
                'case_no': CaseNumber,
                'loc_code': Loc_Code
            },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                rsDevice = result;
                console.log(result);                   //[breakpoint #3]
            },
            failure: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr + ", " + status + ": " + error);
                alert(xhr + ", " + status + ": " + error);
                rsDevice = null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What I expect the console to read like (replacing actual phone numbers & device data with placeholders, of course):

```
555-555-5555
0
get1
{ApplicationCode: '', LDID: 0, LoanerID: ''}   
get2
get3
555-555-5555
0
get1
{ApplicationCode: '', LDID: 0, LoanerID: ''}   
get2
get3
555-555-5555
0
get1
{ApplicationCode: '', LDID: 0, LoanerID: ''}   
get2
get3
. . .
```

What I actually see:

```
555-555-5555
0
get1
get2
get3
555-555-5555
1
get1
get2
get3
{ApplicationCode: '', LDID: 0, LoanerID: ''}
555-555-5555
2
get2
get3
{ApplicationCode: '', LDID: 0, LoanerID: ''}
{ApplicationCode: '', LDID: 0, LoanerID: ''}
555-555-5555
3
get1
get2
{ApplicationCode: '', LDID: 0, LoanerID: ''}
. . .
```

When running the application in Debug Mode in Visual Studio, it hits the breakpoints in the following order: **1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3**. If I move breakpoint #3 to the line above, `rsDevice = result;`, it's the same order.

Why is `getDeviceData` finishing last in the Promise chain? Or, at the very least, finishing at its own pace from the rest? This will affect which device data is applied to which patient/case number, and obviously we don't want a mismatch to occur here.

Comment: You're not waiting for `getDeviceData()`. Neither does `getDeviceData` return a promise, like `getPhoneNumber` does, nor does your `.then()` callback `return` the promise to make the chain wait for it

Comment: "*Why is [it not] finishing at its own pace from the rest?*" - actually it is.

Comment: "*This will affect which device data is applied to which patient/case number*" - don't use global variables for these things. Instead, resolve your promises with the data, and then [properly access these results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi, That did it. Thank you. Posting the answer now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bergi pointed out that I'm not waiting for, nor returning, a promise for `getDeviceData`, which I didn't realize I had to do. Here is my revision, which fixed the issue:

```
    function getExternalData() {
        
            . . . 

            getPhoneNumber(CaseNumber, Loc_Code).then(function (data) {
                console.log(counter);
                console.log('get1');
            }).then(function () {
                return getDeviceData(CaseNumber, Loc_Code);  
                // ^ needed to actually *return* the function
            }).then(function (data) {                        
                // ^ needed to pass the Promise's resolve into the next function
                console.log('get2');
            }).then(function () {
                console.log('get3');
                counter++;
            }).finally(function () {
                getExternalData();
            });
        } else {
            counter = 0;
            $('#content-holder > .appwait').hide();
        }
    }

    . . . 

    function getDeviceData(CaseNumber, Loc_Code) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {  //<== added 
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'api/Phone/PatientDevice',
                data: {
                    'case_no': CaseNumber,
                    'loc_code': Loc_Code
                },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    rsDevice = result;
                    console.log(result);
                    resolve(result);    //<== added
                },
                failure: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(xhr + ", " + status + ": " + error);
                    alert(xhr + ", " + status + ": " + error);
                    phoneNumber = '';
                    reject(error);    //<== added
                }
            });
        });    //<== added
    }
```